# how to get unique path from file explorer in android

Tags: java, android, uri

I want to open file explorer in my app and let the user select some path and save it to my database. after the user selected the path I want to get Uri and save it to the database. this Uri must be unique for all paths.
the problem is that the user can select one path with 2 way and I will get 2 Uri for the same path.

I am using +21 for minimum API.

I am opening file explorer using below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose directory"), 78);
```

here is a result of my download folder. (i don't have external storage in my phone but it has the path of external storage)

I am logging this using uri.toString()

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A
>   content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads

for the first one i open navigation drawer in file explorer and select downloads.
for the second one i open navigation drawer in file explorer and select my internal storage and then select downloads folder.

both of them are same folder in my storage but it has 2 diffrent path.
i want to get same path for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible.

Users can have any number of document providers installed. Those can publish document trees using any `Uri` structure, and they can point to any data that the document providers want. For all you know, a given user could have 1,000 different possible `Uri` values for a given location. And any of them could be returned by `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, depending on what the user chooses in the Storage Access Framework UI. You do not even have a reliable way of determining that two `Uri` values point to the same location.

Comment: I select 1 folder with 2 way. but I expect to get 1 URI for both. because it is the same place.I don't want to get a relative path.

Comment: @l.mome: "but I expect to get 1 URI for both" -- you could get 1,000 different `Uri` values for the same location. Each document provider can do what it wants, and there could be 1,000 different document providers on the device that all happen to let the user choose the same location.